# nrf24l01 frequency switch timing

Tags: arduino, rf, timing, nrf24l01

How much time does the nrf24l01+ take to switch frequency through RF_CH?
Can this switching time be parallel to switch between Tx/Rx/Standby modes?

Comment: I've gone through 24L01 and 24L01+ documentation and I cant find any mention of time required to switch radio frequency. Only one reference to similar timing I could find was on documentation for NRF2401, which is a different (older) chip, which says upto 200us. Will the same apply?
I dont have enough equipment to measure this myself, so any refence to experiments done towards this objective are also welcome.

Comment: If it's not in the datasheet, have you asked the manufacturer (Nordic)?

Comment: No I have not asked Nordic directly. I have posted on their dev forum, but not received any answer yet.  https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/54019/nrf24l01-frequency-switch/

Comment: I did ask Nordic a just few minutes back. Raised a ticket. If I do receive a response from them, I'll post that as answer here. Is their response likely in general experience?

Comment: I used to post in their bluetooth community, Nordic dev zone, and would usually get a response in either a day or two, or not at all. So it's kind of hit or miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a response from Nordic support. Exact text as follows:

> The nRF24L01+ can only change frequency in standby mode. It takes 130 µS from standby to active mode (RX or TX) regardless of you change frequency or not.
>
> This applies for the nRF24LE1 as well.

So as it turns out, switching from standby to Tx/Rx will also setup the RF frequency without requiring any extra time.

Comment: Though I was hoping to switch frequency without going to standby, in Rx mode.. Guess we cant have everything...